# Passing a string between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have the following windows form program in C#:

Form 1 had a ListBox and Button on it. When the Button is pressed it will show Form2 that has a TextBox on it and Button.  When the Button on Form 2 is pressed it will put the text into the ListBox on Form1. Below is the code for each of the forms and then the class I am using.  Any Advice would be great.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        frm2.NewTextChanged += new EventHandler<CustomEvent>(form2_NewTextChanged);
        frm2.ShowDialog();            
        // Unsubscribe from event
        frm2.NewTextChanged -= form2_NewTextChanged;           
        frm2.Dispose();
        frm2 = null;
    }
    private void form2_NewTextChanged(object sender, CustomEvent e)
    {
        //Text = e.Text;
        lbItem.Items.Add(e.Text);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{        
    public event EventHandler<CustomEvent> NewTextChanged;
    private string newText;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string NewText
    {
        get { return newText; }
        set
        {
            if (newText != value)
            {
                newText = value;
                OnNewTextChanged(new CustomEvent(newText));
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnNewTextChanged(CustomEvent e)
    {            
        EventHandler<CustomEvent> eh = NewTextChanged;
        if (eh != null)
            eh(this, e);
    }
    private void btnSendToForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newText = textBox1.Text;
    }
}

public class CustomEvent : EventArgs
{     
    private string text;
    public CustomEvent(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
    }
}
```

I want to use a custom handler.  Any advise?

Comment: I have updated the answer, sorry for the wrong one before

Comment: _When the Button on Form 2 is pressed it will put the text into the ListBox on Form1.  I want to use a custom handler._  When the button on form2 is pressed, should form2 close?...or should this occur possibly multiple times, each time the button is pressed?  Perhaps you meant custom **Event** instead of "handler"?

Comment: When I click the button on form2 to make it add to the listbox on form 1 nothing is added.

Comment: I just posted solution to this problem below. You can refer that. It's a very tiny mistake in the code. I have corrected in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a custom **Event** in Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public delegate void NewText(string item);
    public event NewText NewTextChanged;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NewTextChanged != null)
        {
            NewTextChanged(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

...and here is how Form1 subscribes to that event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.NewTextChanged += Frm2_NewTextChanged;
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void Frm2_NewTextChanged(string item)
    {
        lbItem.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Form1 code, just normal form with show and hide

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.ShowDialog();
            listBox1.Items.Add(f.test);
        }
```

Form2 code
Make a public variable that Form1 can read

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string test;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = textBox1.Text;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good way you are using events for transferring data between forms.

Your code looks OK. It has one problem though due to which it will run fine but the events of Form2 will not fire.

In the clickevent of button of `Form2` you need to set the value of property `NewText` not the field `newText`. So if you change `btnSendToForm1_Click` as following all should work good.

```
private void btnSendToForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.NewText = textBox1.Text;
}
```